# Chef bootstrap command

Tags: chef-infra

Please explore following command to bootstrap a node like what will be my IP and username and password

```
knife bootstrap 123.45.67.89 -x username -P password --sudo --node-name nodename

knife bootstrap 123.45.67.89 -x root -P password --node-name nodename
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Not sure what others understand, but I really don't get what you mean. What part of the [documentation](https://docs.chef.io/knife_bootstrap.html) did you exactly not understand?

Comment: You need to provide the IP address of the node you want to install chef-client on, and username and password for knife to login there.

Comment: Thanks Draco for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

$knife bootstrap ip_address -U username -P password -N node_name

or for using ssh key:

$knife bootstrap ip_address ---ssh-user username  --sudo -i ssh-key -N node_name